# Android issues in wakelock?

Tags: android-wake-lock

Hai i developed a application using broadcast receiver.I need to wake my Application always.so i used wakelock.here my code

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
```

**problem**

1.If i wake up always my battery is getting drained.

2.if i cal `w1.acquier()` ,Is necessary to release the w1`(ie w1.release)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what is your 1st question.. I thought that is a fact if you want to keep waking up your application?

If keep your screen not dimming down is what you want to achieve, you could try this code:

```
            //This is to keep the screen not dimming down.
        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
```

Comment: First question is my charge is getting low coz of WakeLock,is necessary to release() wake lock
this answer is for what question?i cant get you

Answer (score 0):

Wake lock keeps the cpu running on your application even when the screen is off so it will drain your battery hard. You want to call release on your wake lock when you no longer need the application to keep running in the background (example not waiting for any more callbacks).